# Flickrnet and https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flickr

Is there a way to get FlickrNet to use https rather than http? I'm getting "The connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains unencrypted elements (such as images)" in Firefox.

I'd like to just use the https api in Flickr if possible to avoid this.

Or, is there another method I can use to avoid these "mixed content" messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, FlickrNet has now added https, since that's the direction Flickr itself took. It is no longer an issue.